# Load HTML from database into <p:editor/> component primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I'm trying to load the text, which was created by the component . I need to load this text from the data base and put it again inside of this component to allow the Text's editing.

Is that possible?

Sarang

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Just bind the value of your -component to a bean which loads the text from the database

Comment: Yes. The component <p:editor> from primefaces is working fine now. I don't what happened before. thanks